# Swing constants vs component constants

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Which is preferred and why?

```
JLabel.RIGHT
```

or

```
SwingConstants.RIGHT
```

?

**edit**

thank you for your prompt replies, and although my question is answered, it raises another (directly related to my intial question).  if one is "preferred", why allow the other?

```
JLabel jlabel = new JLabel("JLabel",JLabel.RIGHT);  // my preference

JLabel jlabel = new JLabel("JLabel",SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both works but

```
SwingConstants.RIGHT
```

is the preferred one.

Reasons:

- `RIGHT` is declared in and is inherited from `SwingConstants`.
- If `JLabel` would also declare a field named `RIGHT`, it would *hide* the field inerited from `SwingConstants`, and things could get crazy as it might even have different type, visibility and of course value.

In general best would be not to inherit from classes or implement interfaces whose sole purpose is to collect constants.

But even if you do, always refer to them via the class name that defines them to avoid accidential errors introduced later if a new field is added to a subclass with the same name.

Look at this example:

```
class Main implements SwingConstants {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(RIGHT); // Prints 4
    }
}
```

And this:

```
class Main implements SwingConstants {
    private static final int RIGHT = 3;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(RIGHT); // Prints 3
    }
}
```

Our field *hides* `SwingConstants.LEFT`, and it is even of the same type `int` (it could be different type). Good luck tracking down errors caused by these kind of hiding when the type is the same and you get no compile time nor runtime errors.

Answer (score 3):

> `JLabel.RIGHT` or `SwingConstants.RIGHT`

They both are equivalent since [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) implements [SwingConstants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html) interface, inheriting all the constants defined by this interface.

If you just want to save an `import` line for `SwingConstants` interface then you could simply use `JLabel.RIGHT` and evverything will be just fine.

On the other hand if you see lines like this:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

If you don't know the API this code might probably look like a little less verbose and more meaningful than:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

---

### Edit

> [...] and although my question is answered, it raises another
>   (directly related to my intial question). if one is "preferred", why
>   allow the other?

IMHO it's just because a poor design choice when they did `JLabel` (and many other components) implement `SwingConstants` interface in first place. It just makes no sense. That's why I wouldn't care too much in this topic anyway.

If you see [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel-java.lang.String-int-) even those suggest that you should use `SwingConstants` constants:

[image: JLabel javadoc]

Answer (score 1):

JLabel inherit from SwingConstants so i would go with the first wich is a bit more specific and so a bit more meaningfull when your read the code. (If you are manipulating a JLabel of course).

Also I don't remeber encoutering the second in actual code, but that's no a real argument.